# How can I listen SQL Server database with net core SignalR

Tags: .net-core

I want to be informed instantly about the changes made to the database in my project. I can start doing this with ASP.NET MVC but I can't convert it to .NET Core and I can't find resources, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You can not. You need an application and go through the normal standard SQL Server access (ADO.NET) AND - there is no push from the database, so you have to do polling.

Instant notification is generally NOT done from the database but from a server (that also may write to the database while sending the data out to all other clients).